# Corporate client oauth request returns HTTP 401 code

Tags: oauth2, login, authorization, loginflow

To login to my corporate client Salesforce GUI, I have to use the following link:

```
https://theCompany.force.com/partner
```

This link works and logs me in, if I want to log in manually. But when I try to integrate OAuth 2.0 with Salesforce into my application, I, logically, send a request to the following link:

`https://theCompany.force.com/partner/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>`

This generates a valid link, and I am able to log in with it, but along with the response body I receive HTTP code `401`. The workflow of my application is strictly set -- all `4xx` and `5xx` responses are failing. Therefore I cannot proceed with the response from Salesforce. Moreover, a valid auth link and `401` code looks like unexpected behaviour on Salesforce side.

And since I use GuzzleHttp library to process data, it throws `ClientException`...

​Is this a Salesforce bug? Or am I missing something in my implementation? Maybe, I should send an authorization request to some other link?

For instance, `https://theCompany.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize?arguments` (without `/partner`) does not work and sends `503` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, I use `GuzzleHttp` library to process data, and it throws `ClientException` whenever I try to send a request to get *partner* login link.

Since I did not get any adequate response from Salesforce support or developer community,I decided to simply catch the exception:

```
try
{
    return $this->httpClient->get('https://theCompany.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize?' . $arguments)->getEffectiveUrl();
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e)
{
    return $e->getResponse()->getEffectiveUrl();
}
```

Once called `$e->getResponse()->getEffectiveUrl()`, it returns the valid login link.